# Definition of independent components of a tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, tensor-rank

How can the number of independent components of a tensor $T_{i_1 i_2 \dots i_p}$ defined?

**Example:** Let us consider a symmetric matrix $A$ such that $A{}_{ij} = A{}_{ji}$, and hence in $n$ dimensions it has $\#(A) := \frac 12 n(n+1)$ independent components.

**Question:** How can the definition be generalized to accomodate an arbitrary rank-$p$ tensor $T_{i_1 i_2 \dots i_p}$?

**My idea:** Let $T$ be a rank-$p$ tensor regarded as a map $V_p := V \times V \times \dots \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then, let $\Phi_i: V_i \subset V_p$, $i=1,\dots,N$ denote the maximal set of independent projection operators such that

1. $\Phi_i(T) = 0$
2. $\Phi_i \circ \Phi_j = \delta_{ij} \Phi_j$

The number of independent components can then be defined as $\#(T) := \text{dim}\left( V_p \right) - \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \text{dim} \, \text{ker}\left( \Phi_i\right) .$

The weak point in this definition is obviously the vague "maximal set of independent projection operators." How can I make this more precise?

Comment: If you have sets of linear equations tying the elements together ($A_{ij}-A_{ji}=0$ is an example of those), then check the rank for the equation system matrix and use the rank-nullity theorem. If the relations are non-linear it may be more difficult to say anything about the degrees of freedom or independent components.

Comment: I am only considering linear relations at this point, so the equation $A_{ij} - A_{ji} = 0$ is a good example. I am using the rank-nullity theorem already, because if you move the sum $\sum\limits_{i=1}^N$ to the LHS this is exactly what you get. However, I am not sure how to formulate the maximum set of equations of the type $A_{ij} - A_{ji} = 0$.

Comment: Oh okay. Well you can start with vectorizing the tensor. See how large it becomes, and then investigate which matrices define linear equation systems for such a relation you are interested in.

Comment: I suppose. But that does not address the problem that these relations might not be independent. Consider a rank-4 tensor $X_{abcd}$ that satisfies $X_{[ab]cd} = 0$ and $X_{[abc]d} = 0$, where [] denotes antisymmetrization. These expressions are not linearly independent (if written as projectors with proper normalization, their overlap is non-zero if applied successively).

Comment: If they are linear then Kronecker products and vectorizations is what I would use to count them with.